# Spinning up mongo container error: Operation not permitted, Actual exception type: std::system_error

Tags: mongodb, docker

I'm getting the following error when mongoDB is about to be initialised. Anyone has an idea what's wrong? Here are the logs I pulled from the docker container it was running in:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2023-02-19T14:58:03.333+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-02-19T14:58:03.366+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915701, "ctx":"main","msg":"Initialized wire specification","attr":{"spec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":17},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":17},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":6,"maxWireVersion":17},"isInternalClient":true}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-02-19T14:58:03.375+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648601, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen unavailable. If TCP FastOpen is required, set tcpFastOpenServer, tcpFastOpenClient, and tcpFastOpenQueueSize."}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-02-19T14:58:03.389+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationDonorService","namespace":"config.tenantMigrationDonors"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-02-19T14:58:03.415+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationRecipientService","namespace":"config.tenantMigrationRecipients"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-02-19T14:58:03.416+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"ShardSplitDonorService","namespace":"config.tenantSplitDonors"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-02-19T14:58:03.416+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":5945603, "ctx":"main","msg":"Multi threading initialized"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-02-19T14:58:03.416+00:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":6384300, "ctx":"main","msg":"Writing fatal message","attr":{"message":"terminate() called. An exception is active; attempting to gather more information\n"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-02-19T14:58:03.416+00:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":6384300, "ctx":"main","msg":"Writing fatal message","attr":{"message":"std::exception::what(): Operation not permitted\nActual exception type: std::system_error\n\n"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-02-19T14:58:04.943+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31380,   "ctx":"main","msg":"BACKTRACE","attr":{"bt":{"backtrace":[{"a":"555969BB68D4","b":"555964DD8000","o":"4DDE8D4","s":"_ZN5mongo18stack_trace_detail12_GLOBAL__N_119printStackTraceImplERKNS1_7OptionsEPNS_14StackTraceSinkE.constprop.362","C":"mongo::stack_trace_detail::(anonymous namespace)::printStackTraceImpl(mongo::stack_trace_detail::(anonymous namespace)::Options const&, mongo::StackTraceSink*) [clone .constprop.362]","s+":"1F4"},{"a":"555969BB8E19","b":"555964DD8000","o":"4DE0E19","s":"_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceEv","C":"mongo::printStackTrace()","s+":"29"},{"a":"555969BB3167","b":"555964DD8000","o":"4DDB167","s":"_ZN5mongo12_GLOBAL__N_111myTerminateEv","C":"mongo::(anonymous namespace)::myTerminate()","s+":"D7"},{"a":"555969D3DBF6","b":"555964DD8000","o":"4F65BF6","s":"_ZN10__cxxabiv111__terminateEPFvvE","C":"__cxxabiv1::__terminate(void (*)())","s+":"6"},{"a":"555969D3DC31","b":"555964DD8000","o":"4F65C31","s":"_ZSt9terminatev","C":"std::terminate()","s+":"11"},{"a":"555969D3DD6B","b":"555964DD8000","o":"4F65D6B","s":"__cxa_throw","s+":"4B"},{"a":"555966CE747B","b":"555964DD8000","o":"1F0F47B","s":"_ZSt20__throw_system_errori.cold.24","C":"std::__throw_system_error(int) [clone .cold.24]","s+":"2F"},{"a":"555969D59F69","b":"555964DD8000","o":"4F81F69","s":"_ZNSt6thread15_M_start_threadESt10unique_ptrINS_6_StateESt14default_deleteIS1_EEPFvvE","C":"std::thread::_M_start_thread(std::unique_ptr<std::thread::_State, std::default_delete<std::thread::_State> >, void (*)())","s+":"29"},{"a":"555967C8207A","b":"555964DD8000","o":"2EAA07A","s":"_ZN5mongo27startSignalProcessingThreadENS_13LogFileStatusE","C":"mongo::startSignalProcessingThread(mongo::LogFileStatus)","s+":"11A"},{"a":"555966EF81EA","b":"555964DD8000","o":"21201EA","s":"_ZN5mongo11mongod_mainEiPPc","C":"mongo::mongod_main(int, char**)","s+":"B8A"},{"a":"555966CE81BE","b":"555964DD8000","o":"1F101BE","s":"main","s+":"E"},{"a":"7FF08C90DD90","b":"7FF08C8E4000","o":"29D90","s":"__libc_init_first","s+":"90"},{"a":"7FF08C90DE40","b":"7FF08C8E4000","o":"29E40","s":"__libc_start_main","s+":"80"},{"a":"555966EF2A95","b":"555964DD8000","o":"211AA95","s":"_start","s+":"25"}],"processInfo":{"mongodbVersion":"6.0.4","gitVersion":"44ff59461c1353638a71e710f385a566bcd2f547","compiledModules":[],"uname":{"sysname":"Linux","release":"4.15.0-204-generic","version":"#215-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 20 18:24:59 UTC 2023","machine":"x86_64"},"somap":[{"b":"555964DD8000","elfType":3,"buildId":"BCB8F6C3AD4ABF41C81882BAE25C6885C6266CC4"},{"b":"7FF08C8E4000","path":"/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6","elfType":3,"buildId":"69389D485A9793DBE873F0EA2C93E02EFAA9AA3D"}]}}},"tags":[]}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-02-19T14:58:04.976+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"555969BB68D4","b":"555964DD8000","o":"4DDE8D4","s":"_ZN5mongo18stack_trace_detail12_GLOBAL__N_119printStackTraceImplERKNS1_7OptionsEPNS_14StackTraceSinkE.constprop.362","C":"mongo::stack_trace_detail::(anonymous namespace)::printStackTraceImpl(mongo::stack_trace_detail::(anonymous namespace)::Options const&, mongo::StackTraceSink*) [clone .constprop.362]","s+":"1F4"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-02-19T14:58:04.976+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"555969BB8E19","b":"555964DD8000","o":"4DE0E19","s":"_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceEv","C":"mongo::printStackTrace()","s+":"29"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-02-19T14:58:04.976+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"555969BB3167","b":"555964DD8000","o":"4DDB167","s":"_ZN5mongo12_GLOBAL__N_111myTerminateEv","C":"mongo::(anonymous namespace)::myTerminate()","s+":"D7"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-02-19T14:58:04.976+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"555969D3DBF6","b":"555964DD8000","o":"4F65BF6","s":"_ZN10__cxxabiv111__terminateEPFvvE","C":"__cxxabiv1::__terminate(void (*)())","s+":"6"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-02-19T14:58:04.977+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"555969D3DC31","b":"555964DD8000","o":"4F65C31","s":"_ZSt9terminatev","C":"std::terminate()","s+":"11"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-02-19T14:58:04.977+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"555969D3DD6B","b":"555964DD8000","o":"4F65D6B","s":"__cxa_throw","s+":"4B"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-02-19T14:58:04.977+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"555966CE747B","b":"555964DD8000","o":"1F0F47B","s":"_ZSt20__throw_system_errori.cold.24","C":"std::__throw_system_error(int) [clone .cold.24]","s+":"2F"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-02-19T14:58:04.977+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"555969D59F69","b":"555964DD8000","o":"4F81F69","s":"_ZNSt6thread15_M_start_threadESt10unique_ptrINS_6_StateESt14default_deleteIS1_EEPFvvE","C":"std::thread::_M_start_thread(std::unique_ptr<std::thread::_State, std::default_delete<std::thread::_State> >, void (*)())","s+":"29"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-02-19T14:58:04.977+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"555967C8207A","b":"555964DD8000","o":"2EAA07A","s":"_ZN5mongo27startSignalProcessingThreadENS_13LogFileStatusE","C":"mongo::startSignalProcessingThread(mongo::LogFileStatus)","s+":"11A"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-02-19T14:58:04.979+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"555966EF81EA","b":"555964DD8000","o":"21201EA","s":"_ZN5mongo11mongod_mainEiPPc","C":"mongo::mongod_main(int, char**)","s+":"B8A"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-02-19T14:58:04.983+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"555966CE81BE","b":"555964DD8000","o":"1F101BE","s":"main","s+":"E"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-02-19T14:58:04.984+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF08C90DD90","b":"7FF08C8E4000","o":"29D90","s":"__libc_init_first","s+":"90"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-02-19T14:58:04.984+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF08C90DE40","b":"7FF08C8E4000","o":"29E40","s":"__libc_start_main","s+":"80"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-02-19T14:58:04.984+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"555966EF2A95","b":"555964DD8000","o":"211AA95","s":"_start","s+":"25"}}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Found answer on web, it worked for me - need to update Docker: https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/6-0-4-startup-error-on-docker/213908

Comment: Thank you, upgrading Docker worked for me as well.
Mongo 5 started no problem, but when I tried to start 6 or 7, I encountered the same issue.